# Change Quote Owner As Opportunity CreatedBy Name for a Particular Profile

Tags: trigger

I want to change the Quote Owner to be Opportunity CreatedBy Name for a particular profile. I have written Apex code and a Trigger but it is throwing below error while creating a new Quote.

> NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Class.changeOwnerClass.changeOwner: line 14, column 1

Apex method:

```java
public class changeOwnerClass{

    public static void changeOwner(list<Quote> lstQuote){
        List<Id> oppIds = new List<Id>();     
        for (Quote quote: lstQuote) {
            oppIds.add(quote.CreatedById);
        }        
        Map<Id,Opportunity> OppMap = new Map<Id,Opportunity>([Select id, ownerId, CreatedById from Opportunity where id in :oppIds]);
        Profile p = [select id,Name from Profile where id=:Userinfo.getProfileid()];
        for(Quote quote : lstQuote){
            if(p.Name == 'ABC'){
                quote.OwnerId = oppMap.get(quote.CreatedById).CreatedById;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```java
trigger changeOwner on Quote (before insert) {

    if(trigger.isInsert && trigger.isBefore)
    { 
        changeOwnerClass.changeOwner(trigger.new);
    } 
}
```

Could you tell me what needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

You're collecting the quote.CreatedById in a list and querying it against the Opportunity, the Map would be empty.

The exception happens because `oppMap.get(quote.CreatedById)` is null and performing a dot operator on null values gives a null pointer exception.

Quote has a lookup to Opportunity, you need to use that reference instead of CreatedById.

Psuedo code:

```java
public static void changeOwner(list<Quote> lstQuote){
    // using a set is better to avoid duplicates, doesn't matter much here
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();     
    for (Quote quote: lstQuote) {
        oppIds.add(quote.OpportunityId);
    }        
    Map<Id,Opportunity> OppMap = new Map<Id,Opportunity>([Select id, ownerId, CreatedById 
        from Opportunity where id in :oppIds]);
    Profile p = [select id,Name from Profile where id=:Userinfo.getProfileid()];
    for(Quote quote : lstQuote){
        if(p.Name == 'ABC'){
            // may require a null check here
            quote.OwnerId = oppMap.get(quote.OpportunityId).CreatedById;
        }
    }
}
```